# Binomial Generalized Estimation Equation and baboons

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations

I am reading a paper from Science entitled "Shared decision-making drives collective movement in wild baboons'.

In a nutshell, there are two kinds of baboons in this study: (1) those that are initiators of action (to lead, or do other things), and (2) those that are followers (potential to follow, mimic the leader).

Data collected were GPS positions, where (I infer) we can collect real time positions and velocities and directions of the baboons during the interaction.

> "Fitting a binomial generalized estimation equation (GEE) model revealed that a baboon's probability of following depends on the interaction between the number of initiators and their directional agreement."

Here is my question:

1. I actually do not know what GEE is. I have searched and I couldn't find a layman's discussion as to what it is about.
2. Is it possible for someone to give some insight about how the analysis might have taken place given the data? Of course, you can omit the math part. I just want an intuitive flow or a sketch of the train of thought of the analysis and the fitting of the binomial GEE.

Comment: Depends what a layman is but this article http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/157/4/364.abstract may help. Perhaps if it does you can then clarify the second part a bit more as at the moment we would be guessing which bits you do not grasp.

Comment: Thanks. I needed this 'orientation' article because I am totally unfamiliar with it. Let me read this first, and maybe I can ask the right questions next time. I do not even know which tag to use! Thanks again.